# How change tablix on rdlc report to save space?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-tablix

I have a rdlc report that shows results from a dataset SQL query result with 2 columns and +-50 rows, like this:

```
/-----------\
| 1001 | 10 |
|------|----|
| 1002 | 10 |
|------|----|
| 1003 | 12 |
|------|----|
| 1004 | 20 |
|------|----|
| 1005 | 14 |
|------|----|
| 1006 | 32 |
\-----------/
```

It occurs many pages. In order to save space how can i show the results like this:

```
--------+-----  -------+-----  --------+------  --------+----- 
| 1001  | 10 | | 1002  | 10 |  | 1003  | 12 |  | 1004  | 20   |
--------+-----  -------+-----  --------+------  --------+----- 
--------+-----  -------+-----  --------+------  --------+----- 
| 1005  | 14 | | 1006  | 32 |  | 1007  | 19 |  | 1008  | 23   |
--------+-----  -------+-----  --------+------  --------+----- 
...
```

Can be done on report (using table or matrix) or has to be done on the SQL side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After a few tries, i could achive this result:

--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1001  | 1002  |  1003 |  1004 |  1005 |
--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0010 | 0010   | 0012  | 0020  | 0014  |
--------+-------+--------+------+-------+

Using a Matrix and adding an "adjacent after" column group